# VS 2022: Unable to start process. Timeout waiting for child process to open named pipes

Tags: git, visual-studio, team-explorer

I installed VS 2022 few days back and everything was working fine. Suddenly, I started getting the below error

> Unable to start process. Timeout waiting for child process to open
> named pipes.

and since then not able to connect to my Git repo.

I tried Admin mode, repaired VS 2022, upgraded to 17.0.2. Nothing helped.
Now its asking me to "clone the repo" every time I start my visual studio.

Sometime I also get the below message

[image]

On analyzing the XML log, I found below entry in it

```
<entry>
    <record>740</record>
    <time>2021/12/03 09:03:36.264</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [SccProviderPackage]Source: &apos;Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider&apos; Description: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.SccServiceManager.CreateProviderServices(SccProviderPackage providerPackage, Boolean isInServerCommandLineMode, IEnumerable`1 toolWindowAttributes)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.SccProviderPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)</description>
    <guid>{7FE30A77-37F9-4CF2-83DD-96B207028E1B}</guid>
    <hr>80131509</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try command-line Git - if that works, the problem is entirely in VS.

Comment: I also have the same issue since yesterday and like you a repair install did not fix the problem. Whatever has caused it has also broken the git integration in VS 2019 on the same machine. VS Code and command-line Git are fine. I am suspecting the problem may have started after installing Node.js and accepting the optional tools some of which I believe integrate with Visual Studio.

Comment: Admin mode seems to work in some cases for me now. Start VS in admin mode (Run as Administrator) and then open solution using File-> Open Solution option. In this case, it works. But in Non-Admin mode always asking to Clone the repo. I updated to latest 17.0.4 still same issue.

Comment: My Machine Lenovo yoga 12 S1. My VS 2019 enterprise is broken. I install vs 2022, and the git integration giving this error.. 

I try to use TortoiseGit and it is working. It seems Visual Studio getting war with my Lenovo yoga 12. Anyone want to buy my yoga 12?